# Why is Page Control not reflecting where I am on the UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

After editing my UIScrollView size, page control stopped working.

[image: Example]

You can see there are only 3 slides. But (1) Page Control isn't reflecting which slide I'm on and (2) I can only scroll from slide 1 to slide 3.

Here's my code:

```
func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [Slide]) {
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 154)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 188 * CGFloat(slides.count) + CGFloat((slides.count - 1) * 10), height: 153)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    var lastCellMaxX: CGFloat = 0
    let constantSpacingBetweenCell: CGFloat = 10

    for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
        slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: lastCellMaxX, y: 0, width: 220, height: 153)
        scrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
        lastCellMaxX += 188 + constantSpacingBetweenCell
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
}
```

Comment: You are not showing enough code. When is `setupSlideScrollView` called? It makes a big difference. Also your "magic numbers" (154, 188, 220, 153) are a bad smell.

Comment: 1. `setupSlideScrollView` is inside of `viewDidLoad`. It is called inside of my API call (I get the weather data, and then create the slides, all inside viewDidLoad).
2. I'm sure those magic numbers could be improved (I'm new to Swift). What's a better option?

Comment: "setupSlideScrollView is inside of viewDidLoad" That could be the problem, because your view does not yet have its real `frame` at that point, so your `view.frame.width` will give your scroll view the wrong width.

Comment: Thanks @matt! You were right, now the Page control reflects the changes... but I have one final error. When I scroll through the slides, it goes directly from slide 1 to slide 3. I didn't change my code (other than using Mocha's solution below). So what could be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
// This will always round down to zero 
// since the contentOffset.x will always be smaller than the frame width...
    let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width) 
// Possible logic to correct this?
    let pageIndex = scrollView.contentOffset.x / (width of a slide)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
}
```

-- Updated due to chat --

Your scrollview's frame is fine. However, you need to add a stackview to hold all your slides in order to scroll through it. Scrollviews are a bit tricky since you can't just add views and expect it to be scrollable.

Here is test code I used to create a scrollView that contains stackviews.

```
func createSlideshow() {
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let slide1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 375))
    slide1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let slide2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 375))
    slide2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    let slide3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 375))
    slide3.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    let slides: [UIView] = [slide1, slide2, slide3]
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .center
    stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
    stackView.spacing = 10
    for slide in slides {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(slide)
        slide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: slide.frame.width).isActive = true
        slide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ 
But what you said made sense... Where else do you think the issue could be?

Comment: I would like to know the scrollview.contentOffset.x and the width of the slides in this method.

Comment: I fixed this error using matt's comment and your solution. Thank you! But now I have one final error... When I scroll, it goes directly from Slide 1 to Slide 3 (without stopping at Slide 2). My code looks the same, except I added you change. What could be wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure.. What is the scrollview.contentOffset.x when you think the current slide should be at 2? What is the width of a slide? What is the whole scrollview.frame.size.width?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `scrollview.contentOffset.x` is when the current slide is at 2. But I fount that the `scrollview.frame.size.width` is 375 and the width of a slide is 220. I'm guessing I should make the frame bigger?

Comment: Put a print statement in the scrollViewDidScroll method and see what the contentOffset is when you expect it to be at slide 2.

Comment: It gave a lot of numbers between 96 and 281

Comment: When you originally scroll, does it print 0. And if you scroll all the way to the right.. does it stop at 375?

You should only be reaching slide 1 and 2. You shouldn't be reaching slide 3

Comment: Hmm... it only prints from 0 all the way to 282. Not 375. This is odd.

Comment: Oh wait. Now I changed scrollView.contentsize back to width 188 and yes it does stop at slide 2 like you said. (and prints from 0 to 246)

Comment: See updated answer -- You never actually implemented Matt's solution.

Comment: I did! And the Page Control started working again. The only problem is it jumps over slide 2 straight to slide 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190546/discussion-between-mocha-and-richard-reis).

Comment: @RichardReis You accepted the answer -- does it work now?

Comment: Part of the answer worked. The dots appear and reflect the right slide. This is why I accepted the answer (the only problem that needs fixing now is this jump from Slide 1 to Slide 3 without stopping on Slide 2)

Comment: I updated the answer with working stackview in scrollview